# routing table with multiple same destination

Tags: ping, route

I'm learning the "route" command for LPIC-1 exam. I cannot figure out how routing works based on the following example:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     207    0        0 veth609b6e7
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     209    0        0 veth68250aa
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     211    0        0 veth97da831
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     213    0        0 vethaef1d51
[...]
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-acc7c3b7b431
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Suppose that a user types:

```
ping 169.254.1.1
```

To which Destination/Gateway/Iface is the ICMP packet routed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll go out `veth609b6e7`, because that route has the lowest metric to the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_(networking)